# How to specify a child scope for constructor func factory parameter?

Tags: c#, scope, autofac, lifetime, object-lifetime

I want to do something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    Func<OtherClass> _factory;
    public MyClass([WithChildScope("OtherClassScope")] Func<OtherClass> other)
    {
        _factory = other;
    }

    public OtherClass LoadOther(int id)
    {
        var entity = DbHelper.LoadEntity(id);
        var other = _factory();
        other.Configure(entity);
        return other;
    }
}
```

So that each call to `LoadOther` should create a new `OtherClass` instance with its own scope (inside a parent scope in which `MyClass` was constructed). But there is no `[WithChildScope]` attribute.

In NInject I would use `DefinesNamedScope` with *ContextPreservation*.

Can I do it in AutoFac without passing *locator* everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution myself:

```
k.RegisterType<Scoped<UserScope>>().AsSelf().WithParameter("childTag", "User");

public class Scoped<T>
{
    public Scoped(ILifetimeScope scope, object childTag)
    {
        Value = scope.BeginLifetimeScope(childTag).Resolve<T>();
    }

    public T Value { get; }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    Func<Scoped<UserScope>> _factory;

    public UserRepository(Func<Scoped<UserScope>> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
}
```